# Convert String to XlChartType in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In a worksheet I store a list of charts that I wish to create using VBA. For instance it would contain in a column:

- xl3DArea
- xlLine

In my VBA routine I define a `XlChartType` variable as follows:

```
Dim chartType               As XlChartType
```

Later in the same routine I try to read in the chart type from the worksheet and assign it to the chartType variable using the following code (other code lines in with block removed):

```
With Worksheets(chartDetailsWorksheet)

    'Variable initialisations
    chartType = Cells(2, 2).value

End With
```

But the code fails as the value read from the worksheet is treated as a string (not surprising). I've tried looking on line for an answer but...
I was thinking, like in other languages, you could do a type conversion to fix this issue quickly. But all I've found so far is a site talking of writing custom functions to convert the string value into `XlChartType` values.

Is this the only way to handle this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to convert as string constant name into its value. Whether you should is a different question.

```
Function WhatIsTheValue(s As String) As Variant

        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("modTemp")
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

        With CodeMod
            .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            .InsertLines 1, "Public Function GetTheValue()"
            .InsertLines 2, "GetTheValue = (" & s & ")"
            .InsertLines 3, "End Function"
        End With
        WhatIsTheValue = Application.Run("GetTheValue")

End Function
```

Comment: Better appraoch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230772/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-chart-in-excel-has-its-series-stacked-or-not/27234857#27234857

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

On the sheet, store values in two columns, one visible, one hidden.
In the hidden column put numerical values for enum members. In the visible column put descriptive names (`xlLine` is not a descriptive name for a user). Then read the hidden column.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the initial answer but I think there is a slight bit of confusion. "xlLine" isn't a user name in this case (I'd agree it wouldn't be a good user name) but it is in fact an enumeration value for the xlChartType. It denotes a basic line chart. But I get what you mean...

Comment: @DarkLord_109 By "name for a user" I meant "Name you display to a user," not "name of the user." I'm saying, put the numerical value of `xlLine` (which is `4`) into a cell, and into an adjacent cell put something like "Line chart."

Comment: along these lines you might reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241008(v=office.12).aspx for XlChartType s

Answer (score 0):

I understand you've expressed reservations about a custom function, but honestly that is the route I would take, rather than hidden columns which can be accidentally manipulated/deleted/etc., either by user intervention or code execution.

This subroutine takes the string value from Cells(2,2) and converts it to xlChartType by passing it through the function, below.

```
Sub ChartTypes()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stringType As String
Dim chartType As XlChartType

Set ws = Sheets(1)

stringType = CStr(Cells(2, 2).Value)

'Use the function to return the correct xlChartType in the AddChart:
Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart( _
        GetChartTypeConstant(stringType), _
        50, 50, 300, 200).Chart
End Sub
```

And here is the function which is called within the `Set cObj...`.  Note that by using a function with case select would allow you to use more user-friendly names, instead of "xlBarClustered" you could call it "Horizontal Bars", etc.

```
Private Function GetChartTypeConstant(myString As String) As XlChartType
'This function returns an xlCharType constant value from a descriptive string
' which you will need to define or modify for your needs;
' using select case also means you can use more descriptive/user-friendly
' names on your worksheet.

    Select Case myString
    Case "xlBarClustered", "Clustered Bars", "Horizontal Bars"
        GetChartTypeConstant = xlBarClustered
    Case "xlColumnClustered", "Clustered Columns", "Vertical Columns"
        GetChartTypeConstant = xlColumnClustered
    Case "xlLine", "Lines Only"
        GetChartTypeConstant = xlLine

    'Additional cases can be added for
    ' additional chart types.
End Select


End Function
```

Please note there is no error-handling in either the sub or function.